# Escaping ampersands (&) on generated requests from a WCF class

Tags: wcf, soap, .net-core, svcutil.exe

I'm having issues with strings containing ampersands in my client generated from dotnet-svcutil.

When I recieve a response through the client all ampersands are serialized as

```
<Users xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">John &amp; Jane</Users>
```

When i extract the value from the request in my code it has been deserialized as an ampersand

```
UserResponse users  = await GetUsersAsync()

users.Names = "John & Jane"
```

In a later stage i need to send the value of the users back like this

```
await SetUsersAsync(users.Names);
```

When i intercept the generated soap request I can see that the ampersand has not been escaped

```
public class MyMessageInspector : IClientMessageInspector
    {
        public void AfterReceiveReply(ref Message reply, object correlationState)
        {
            var xml = reply.ToString(); // This shows <Users xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">John &amp; Jane</Users>
        }

        public object BeforeSendRequest(ref Message request, IClientChannel channel)
        {
            var xml = request.ToString(); // This shows <Users xsi:type=\"xsd:string\">John & Jane</Users>

            return null;
        }
    }
```

This causes the whole request to fail in the connected service. From the information I've found online the ampersand should be converted to `&amp;` by the serializer. I could convert the value myself, but since I'm only returning a value I got from the soap client, I would have to check and convert every single string that is returned back.

Do you have any suggestions on how I could configure the generated client to automatically escape ampersands?

Answer (score 0):

For .net core 2.1+:
Use the `HtmlEncode` method of `HttpUtility` available in `System.Web` to encode the strings you send to the client.

```cs
using System.Web;

await SetUsersAsync(HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(users.Names));
```

For .net core 2.0 (or .net 1.* with a  package install):

use `HtmlEncoder.Default.Encode(users.Names)`

which is available in `System.Text.Encodings.Web`

Comment: Thank you for answering! But the problem is that I want to configure the generated client to encode the reserved characters automatically upon serialization

Comment: Not sure if it can be done automatically. I would just encode any string that I send in as shown in the example above.